# Jquery passing the name of file and file path from input dialog.. to controller MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I pass an input dialog file name and file path using jquery / json to controller using MVC 3?

I am using ado.net.

any help or anywhere to look for this?

Thanks

Comment: are you talking about ajax?? you cant pass any client side value to server without it ... m not a .net expert but this is genenral

Comment: I have a dialog <input type="file" /> and want to get the file name and file path and pass it to my controller ... I can pass a value to my controller as such: post.push(name: 'name', value: 4);

Comment: in that case their is nothing to do with jquery ...u can pass it through form post or via url (dont know how you achieve this in .net), . If you want you can use ajax(via jquery/javascript) to post your values to server.

Comment: You actually probably won't be able to consistently get the file path, using a `<input type="file" />` - for security reasons, a number of browsers display a fake path (C:\fakepath\filename in chrome, for instance)

Comment: so what will be your suggestion Chris? I need to get the file and file name and store them in a database .. the issue is how to pass them from view to my model.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what happens to the file? I mean, MVC runs on a webserver. It's a web application. The user is picking a file from their local computer - the path on their computer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to post an answer on how to upload a file in MVC3

In your controller, you need a method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload( HttpPostedFileBase file )
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[file.InputStream.Length];
    file.InputStream.Read( buffer, 0, (int)file.InputStream.Length );
    // You need to have some method of saving the bytes of this file, or use the 
    // file.SaveAs() method to save this to a targeted directory your web server
    // has access to
    YourCode.SaveFile( buffer, file.FileName );
    return View( );
}
```

And a view set up like so:

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm("FileUpload","YourControllerName",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will upload the file